# can't read a special character ́ in python

Tags: python, special-characters

I have a program in python to read the following string

```
gh ́gfh
```

in this string the character at position 3 is `́`   and the character at position 4 is g, you can identify by cut and paste that position.

but I can't read the character `́`  at position 3 in the string.

I have tried to convert to both string and unicode, but problem still remains.

and the program is as follows,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

import io

f = io.open("mapping_input.txt",'r')

while True:

    c = f.read(1)
    if not c:
        break
    else:
        print c
```

Comment: And what is the exact problem? Do you get an error? What exactly is the full traceback in that case?

Comment: And what happens when you use `print repr(c)`, what is the output then?

Comment: You mean you can't _print_ it or you can't _read_ it?

Comment: no errors. but can't read the character as such, and the print repr(c) gives u'\u0301' as output, There is no problem regarding printing the character, if i read it correctly. problem is not properly reading it. 
 but manually i can print it as follows, it works to just print. # coding=utf-8
c = ' ́'
print c

Answer (score 0):

When doing I/O, you need to know the data format. For text files, this means you need to know the **encoding** or **charset**. So the first step is to find out how `mapping_input.txt` was created and with which encoding it was saved. If you used `UTF-8`, for example, then you can read the file using the `codecs` module:

```
f = codecs.open("mapping_input.txt", 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Please learn how to ask for help. "problem" is never a suitable description. Give us the stack trace and the exact error message. Don't let us guess what "problem" might be.